# how to downgrade gcc version in mint/ubuntu

Tags: gcc

I'm using gcc 4.6. in my linux. But I want to use gcc-3.3.5 version. I remove current gcc version and try to install sudo apt-get install gcc-3.3.5.
But it says
Unable to locate package gcc-3.3.5 &
Couldn't find any package by regex 'gcc-3.3.5'

I think it's the fact of no repository in source list to install gcc-3.3.5

Help to overcome this problem

Comment: you should check apt docs for downgrading or install it from src

Comment: Why do you really need gcc 3.3.5? It is a very old version (unmaintained, not up to date).. Why cannot you still use GCC 4.6 ??? I'm almost sure it should compile your code (otherwise, your code is broken, perhaps because it uses non-standard language construct; and then you should fix it).

Answer (score 0):

### Don't downgrade your GCC compiler

As I said in a comment, there is **no reason to downgrade your `gcc` compiler**. The current version `4.6` works fine, and bring you a lot of features that previous versions didn't. It is in practice related to the kernel you are running, thru the `libc` library supporting it.

And an ancient version such as GCC 3.3 probably won't work on your system (it may depend upon `libc` misfeatures or anachronisms which have been improved since).

You might try to compile an ancient version like GCC 3.3 from its source code, but you probably will have trouble doing that. Again, I recommend not doing this.

If you really wanted to downgrade your compiler, the easiest way is to install an ancient Linux distribution. I recommend not doing that - because your recent hardware would be unsupported -.
(You might try to do that in a `chroot`-ed environment with `debootstrap`).

If you want to downgrade your GCC compiler because you have an ancient source code to compile, try finding the permissive options (perhaps `-fpermissive`) or better yet, patch your source code so that `gcc-4.6 -Wall` don't give any warnings or error.

Feel free to ask questions about how to improve your source code (in particular if it is free software) that motivates you (wrongly) to downgrade your compiler.

Even the standards that GCC implement have made some progress since its version 3.3.

Comment: I came across this question because I have a Python ctypes-based interface to SWI-Prolog that runs fine with the SWI-Prolog .so library when it is compiled on the 2.6.38 Linux kernel (Linux Mint 11) with GCC 4.5.2 but has segfaults when the library is compiled on the 3.2.0 Linux kernel (Linux Mint 13) with GCC 4.6.3

This is the strangest error I have ever seen and I don't know what is the issue here.  Is it a kernel issue?  A problem with GCC?  No idea.  Should I find some way to downgrade my GCC compiler on Linux Mint 13 to 4.5.2?  Or is that pointless?